# filtering radio buttons in jquery, comparing values

Tags: jquery, radio-button, filtering

I have the following code. Trying to prepopulate a radio button based on an incoming array value. It will be 1-3

```
<input name="rating1" type="radio" value="1" />
<input name="rating1" type="radio" value="2" />
<input name="rating1" type="radio" value="3" />

$(document).ready(function() {                         
    //Setting  up the radio buttons                    
    var $radios = $('input:radio[name=rating1]');
        //ratingAnswer is the value I need to select in the radio group. Value=2
    var ratingAnswer=answersArray[oneMap].RATING;
      if($radios.is(':checked') === false) {
        $radios.filter('[value=ratingAnswer]').attr('checked', true);
}
```

This returns me nothing as it is looking for the string ratingAnswer as the value and not the variable value of ratingAnswer. I have tried value=' + ratingAnswer + ' but it doesn't like that at all. How can I inject a variable into that value area. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

```
$radios.filter('[value="' + ratingAnswer + '"]').attr('checked', true);
```

If this still doesn't work, take a close look at the value of `ratingAnswer` to see if it's what you expect.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/1/

Comment: For setting `checked` value, use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Answer (score 2):

You should change this line:

```
 $radios.filter('[value=ratingAnswer]').attr('checked', true);
```

for this one:

```
 $radios.filter('[value='+ratingAnswer+']').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this – that doesn't assume values will not conflict with jQuery selector syntax – is as follows:

```
$radios.filter(function() { return this.value == varWithValueToBeChecked; }).prop('checked', true);
```